# jquery get array of buttons and their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Im new in JS and Jquery.
I have been trying to set an event to all buttons in the same class, meanwhile I'm tryinh to get the value of each button.

In my HTML I got:

```
<div id="highlightButtons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="9">9</button>
</div>
```

And in my JS I tried this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    var all_hl_btns = $('#highlightButtons');
    all_hl_btns.click(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        alert(value);
    });
}());
```

At this point, I'm just trying get the value of each button that I click, but when I click in any button, I got a text of numbers (1 to 9) in a Column.
I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change `$('#highlightButtons')` to `$('button')`.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad... It worked, place that as a reply and I will mark as answer!

Comment: Or `#highlightButtons button` if you want to restrict the event handler to only the buttons within that container

Comment: Or even `$("#highlightButtons button").toArray()` if you wanted an "array of buttons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to add click event to `#highlightButtons` and when you click on it, javascript get text of it that is *123456789*. You need to add click event to buttons. In the case, your selector changed to `$('#highlightButtons > button')`

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    var all_hl_btns = $('#highlightButtons > button');
    all_hl_btns.click(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        alert(value);
    });
}());
```

```js
var all_hl_btns = $('#highlightButtons > button');
all_hl_btns.click(function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="highlightButtons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="4">4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="5">5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="6">6</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="7">7</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="8">8</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="9">9</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer!